# Not finished business logic of the trigger

Tags: sql, oracle

I have such trigger(when adding some ticket to table Cancel, then this ticket set free in table Ticket). But what if this ticket is already free, so there is no need to cancel it. What to add to do such logic(when I add free ticket to table Cancel then it causes an error)?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CANCEL_TICKET
  AFTER INSERT ON CANCEL
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    UPDATE TICKET
      SET TICKET.CLIENT_ID = NULL
    WHERE TICKET.TICKET_ID = :NEW.TICKET_ID;
  END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correclty:

You can use an IF statement like this:

```
IF (SELECT TICKET.CLIENT_ID FROM TICKET
    WHERE TICKET.TICKET_ID = :NEW_TICKET_ID) IS NOT NULL THEN

    UPDATE TICKET
      SET TICKET.CLIENT_ID = NULL
    WHERE TICKET.TICKET_ID = :NEW.TICKET_ID;
END IF;
```

Comment: I have one more question to you: what is FOR EACH ROW for? What does it do? And what happens when not using this block?

Comment: Is this select correct? SELECT TICKET.CLIENT_ID FROM TICKET.TICKET_ID

Comment: @user3238724: I've update, sorry for my fault; for each row works on every row inserted because the trigger in on INSERT on CANCEL

Comment: but this still doesn't work. Error: PLS-00103 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CANCEL_TICKET
  AFTER INSERT ON CANCEL
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF SELECT TICKET.CLIENT_ID FROM TICKET
    WHERE TICKET.TICKET_ID = :NEW.TICKET_ID IS NOT NULL THEN
      UPDATE TICKET
        SET TICKET.CLIENT_ID = NULL
      WHERE TICKET.TICKET_ID = :NEW.TICKET_ID;
    END IF;
  END;